# How to intercept tap on a UITabelView row when that row is not a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios

I used to work like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

But now I have to do the same thing on a cell that is not a UITableViewCell:
I had to put in cells a lot of stuff, so i couldn't use normal UITableViewCells, and I made it my own (called PrototypeTableViewCell). Like this:

```
@interface PrototypeTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *eventTitle;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *eventLocation;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *eventStartDate;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *eventEndDate;

@end
```

So how can I do the things I used to do on normal TableViewCells (like setting the accessory:checkmark)?
"cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath" won't work with the class I created.

Answer (score 4):

Your PrototypeTableViewCell is a subclass of UITableViewCell. All you need to do is simply cast UITableViewCell to your PrototypeTableViewCell as follows:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  // cast UITableViewCell to your PrototypeTableViewCell
  PrototypeTableViewCell *cell = (PrototypeTableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  // use its properties as normal
  cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```

Comment: @Ales Just to add to this (it's bad to just provide code without explanation). Your cell is not a "prototype" it is a subclass of `UITableViewCell`. It still IS a `UITableViewCell` you have just added some custom stuff to it. So the function will still work you just have to cast it into your custom subclass.

Comment: Sorry about that. An edit was made to the code example above.